# ERROR: Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

When I send it to the login screen again as the logout part in the application I developed, I get this error.

**Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.**

I do the logout method as follows. Do I need to dispose of Global Keys? Can you help me?

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Yoklama()),
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

This Happens Because your login screen isn't closed and you're trying to reopen it when you click logout.

If the above code doesn't work on your side then try this.

When you login then use this navigator:

```
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => YourHomePageScreen()),
        );
```

And when you logout then use this

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Yoklama()),
              );
```